# Using KVO to update table cells from model upon any change to model

Tags: ios, uitableview, model, uikit, key-value-observing

I may have multiple table cells which are updated from the same model. I want to be able to update all of them when the model changes. So I assume I will use KVO to do that. My question is, how can I have each react to any change to the model, not just the part that each cell will display? i.e. if one item in the model changes, I want all of the cells to update themselves.

Answer (score 0):

try to use tableView.reloadData() immediately after changing the model. On the other hand you may also try to use RxSwift and bind your model items to tableView - your tableview will then reload whenever the model changes. Refer to these articles as simple examples of RxSwift usage with tableView:
http://rx-marin.com/post/bind-multiple-cells/
https://daddycoding.com/2020/04/20/rxswift-uitableview-with-section/

Answer (score 0):

> So I assume I will use KVO to do that.

Table cells are very transient -- the cell for a given row in your table will get reused for a different row almost as soon as it scrolls off the screen. So long-term relationships really aren't something that cells are good at, and you probably don't want to go setting a cell up to observe part of your model directly. Instead, let the view controller worry about the model and reload any affected cells when the model changes. If you want to use key-value observing to let the view controller watch the model, that'll work fine.

> My question is, how can I have each react to any change to the model, not just the part that each cell will display?

When the view controller learns that the model has changed, it should tell the table to reload its data. At that point, the table will go through the process of recreating the visible cells, and the effect will be that all the cells will appear to "update themselves."

Comment: These cells will stay around for a while. It is true that the user may scroll. But minimizing updates to the entire table, which may have 1000 items, seems like it ought to be the priority. The app is basically a social app so the updates to models will be frequent and the user's attention will be fixated on some for a while that will minimize scrolling.

Comment: That's not how it works. The table may have 1000 rows, but it won't have nearly 1000 cells. When you `reloadData`, the table view will only ask its data source to recreate the cells for rows that are visible. And your life will be a lot easier if you follow the normal pattern until there's an actual reason not to.

Comment: Yes, I know that. However it's very inefficient to reload the table everytime just one row needs to be updated. If that is really how it works, it is a bad design on Apple's part.

Comment: Creating new views is pretty expensive. Reconfiguring them not so much. The whole point is to avoid the cost of constantly creating and destroying views. I’m not saying you can’t use KVO from cells, but you’ll be constantly adding and removing observers as the cells change identity, and that may be expensive too. In the normal pattern the controller just changes the data in a handful of cells and that’s it. If fetching data from your model is costly, you’ll have the same problem with KVO.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to reload table by using `tableView.reloadData()` after the data changed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29173241)

Comment: @Rob Sorry I edit the answer. Please check and tell me if it's still not good.